# How to extract the Text in the following Image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I want to Detect the Text in the Image. I have applied the EasyOCR to the Image but the results are not good, e.g

The expected result is **부동산 매매 계약서**

But my code output is **부 동 산 떼 더 겨 약 서**

[image]
Can any body help me with this

```
!pip install easyocr
import cv2
import easyocr
import numpy as np
def extract_text_from_image(image):
    # Read the image
    #image = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # Convert the image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply adaptive thresholding to create a binary image
    _, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    # Find contours in the binary image
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Find the contour with the maximum area (foreground)
    max_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

    # Create a mask for the foreground contour
    mask = np.zeros_like(binary)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [max_contour], 0, 255, -1)

    # Apply the mask to the original image
    preprocessed_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

    # Initialize the EasyOCR reader
    reader = easyocr.Reader(['en','ko'])

    # Convert the preprocessed image to grayscale
    preprocessed_gray = cv2.cvtColor(preprocessed_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Perform OCR on the preprocessed image
    results = reader.readtext(preprocessed_gray)

    # Concatenate the extracted text into a single line
    extracted_text = ''
    for result in results:
        extracted_text += result[1] + ' '

    return extracted_text.strip()



img = cv2.imread(file_path)
text = extract_text_from_image(img)
```

Output from first letter should be
**부동산 매매 계약서**
this result is correct.

Comment: may be your image is of low resolution so the distinction between the letters can't be identified? Can you check with a high resolution image?

Comment: @AllІѕVаиітy I have only this Image.

Comment: If you look at a magnified image showing the pixels you will see that there is not enough discrimination in the problem characters for OCR to properly detect and resolve.

Comment: @user19077881 Then How can i solve this problem

Comment: If you can't get a higher resolution image then all I can think of is some form of contextual language processing but I have no idea if this is possible.

Comment: @user19077881 Please give a code so that it can be generate some output

Comment: Unfortunately not all problems can be solved.